# How to use regexp to replace this string in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string like `/233/ziyuanku/Screenshot_2014-09-03-16-11-45.png` or `/233/ziyuanku/37770506/edit.png`

I want to remove the `/233` and get the last string `/ziyuanku/Screenshot_2014-09-03-16-11-45.png`

My strings are like 
a `/`,
a number,
and a path, may have a number_name.

I can get the regexp `'/\d+(.*)'`, but I don't know how to do it in JavaScript.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: use the first capturing group to capture the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex

```
function replaceName(url){

    var match = /^\/\d+(\/.*)$/.exec(url);
    if(match){
        return match[1];
    }

}
```

replaceName('/233/ziyuanku/Screenshot_2014-09-03-16-11-45.png');//returns /ziyuanku/Screenshot_2014-09-03-16-11-45.png

Comment: Thank you. And I have another question. How to remove the file_name and only save the path? Like `/ziyuanku/Screenshot_2014-09-03-16-11-45.png` to `/ziyuanku/`. I tried $ but didn't find the right way.

Comment: /^\/\d+(\/([^\/+]))(\/.*)$/ will give you the file name.   match[2] is the name you wanted.  match[3] Will give you the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a regex, as follows:

```
var name = "John/Smith";
var re = /([^A-Za-z])/g;
var subst = ' ';
name.replace(re, subst);
```

result: "John Smith"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
str = '/233/ziyuanku/Screenshot_2014-09-03-16-11-45.png';
result = str.replace(/\/[0-9]+/, '');
```